# Getting error while loading MNIST data

Tags: python, neural-network, importerror

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    training_data, validation_data, test_data = mnist_loader.load_data_wrapper()
  File "mnist_loader.py", line 68, in load_data_wrapper
  File "mnist_loader.py", line 42, in load_data
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 34, in open
    return GzipFile(filename, mode, compresslevel)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 94, in __init__
    fileobj = self.myfileobj = __builtin__.open(filename, mode or 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../data/mnist.pkl.gz'
```

I am getting this error; It is clear to me that it is asking for correct path but I tried it in many ways like:

1. C:\Users\home\neural-networks-and-deep-learning-master
2. D:\neural-networks-and-deep-learning-master
3. C:\neural-networks-and-deep-learning-master
4. C:\Users\home\neural-networks-and-deep-learning-master\data
5. C:\Users\home\neural-networks-and-deep-learning-master\src
6. D:\Users\home\neural-networks-and-deep-learning-master\data

...

But still I am not getting done with the error.

I am new to python and working on neural-network & deeplearning.

Comment: How about looking where that file is instead of randomly picking directories?

Comment: How we will do that? I was supposing the file location to be started with some sort of directory?

Comment: [How to search files in Windows](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+search+files+in+Windows)

Comment: Now I got you. No, I wasn't randomly picking it. When ever I changed directory, I changed files location too in the same directory. I was trying it with the thought that there must be problem with directory.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Resolved.

I was making mistake with this part " '../data/mnist.pkl.gz' " of my mnist_loader.py file. I didn't change the " .. " to the directory where I located this mnist_loader.py file.

That's why It was giving this error:

`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../data/mnist.pkl.gz'`